# Adding a Half screen Navigation controller to iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

In my iPad application i need to implement a navigation controller behavior to the right half of the screen( I can't use split view controller because i need more space in left-side - around 600px). Is there any way to create a NavigationController with a fixed frame size ?

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply:

- create navigation controller;
- set navigationController.view.frame to necessary frame;
- add navigationController.view as you main view's or window's subview.

Somsing like this:

```
navigationController.view.frame = necessaryFrame;
[viewController addSubview:navigationController.view];
```